# Android Support Library 22.1 and AlertDialog bug?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I tried to update my AlterDialog to the new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog, just changing the:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
```

The new AlertDialogs are shown as Material style now on Pre-Lollipop, but the dialog window is much wider (tested on a Tablet).
Is this not a bug? Should be the android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog the same width than android.app.AlertDialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Material specification.

However you can customize this spec, usign a custom theme. For example something like this:

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
       <!-- background, accent color..... -->

       <item name="windowMinWidthMajor">30%</item>
       <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">30%</item>
   </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Material design generally makes use of more whitespace and greater margins / padding than previous Android design, so no - it's not a bug.

It matches the specifications listed here:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html

Comment: So, why when I use android.app.AlertDialog on a Lollipop device and android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog on the same Lollipop device, the "android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog" is much wider? Should be the same. For a small dialog creates a extreme wide window.